# Как добавить файл который находится подпапке

Tags: cmake

у меня есть проект такой структуры

```
CMakeLists.txt   
main.cpp
```

но я хотел бы перенести `main.cpp` в папку `src`, а папку `src` поместить возле `CMakeLists.txt`. как это можно сделать?

Вот как я хочу сделать:

```
CMakeLists.txt   
src/main.cpp
```

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИМХО включать файлы из поддиректории напрямую — моветон. Это ухудшает структуру проекта, усложняет поиск хедеров и может давать конфликты расположения объектников.

Хорошей практикой является иметь свой `CMakeLists.txt` в каждом каталоге:

**./CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# ...
add_subdirectory(src)
```

**./src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
```

Comment: Здесь стоит указать, что это разумная практика, если файлы из субдиректорий принадлежат разным библиотекам или экзешникам - в противном случае это будет бессмысленным

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, я предпочитаю всегда из них собирать статическую библиотеку... а, если хочу энфорсить структурную независимость, то, для отладки, и динамические...

Answer (score 0):

Ничего сложного или невероятного: просто вместо "main.cpp" напишите "src/main.cpp"